# Vertex names by creating a network object via an edgelist (R package: network)

Tags: r, networking

I want to create a network object, representing a directed network on basis of an edgelist. The first column contains some unique ID of project leaders, the second project partners, let's say:

```
library("network")
x <- cbind(rbind(1,1,2,2,3), rbind(3,7,10,9,6)) 
y.nw <- network(x, matrix="edgelist", directed=TRUE, loops=FALSE)
```

Now my problem is: I need all vertexes to have the right ID, since after creating the network object I have to transfer it back to a adjacency matrix with the right corresponding firm IDs. However, I am not sure in which order I should assign them, since I sorted the dataframe by column 1 (project leaders), which, however, not always show up as project partners as well.

Comment: Or to reformulate the question slightly: Anyone has an idea, how to transform a (directed) edgelist into an asymmetric adjacency matrix, which has the correct IDs to be found in the edgelist in its corresponding rows and columns? 

Any help is highly appreciated! Best D.

Answer (score 0):

If your ids are sequential integers as in your example, you can produce the adjacency matrix corresponding to the edgelist in your example with:

```
>as.sociomatrix(y.nw))
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
2  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  1
3  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0
4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
7  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
8  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
9  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
```

But maybe you have a different type of id system in your real input?